# Information regarding /proc file system

Tags: file-system

Yesterday I rooted my android phone. By using Es File Explorer when I see the file listing then I find various folders.

For the sake of curiosity I would like to know that what the **proc** file system contains.

Comment: It's a virtual file-system from the Linux kernel which contains information about the running processes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a detailled explanation of what is in the /proc directory [in the linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)